# Zxing OS X demo not compiling

Tags: objective-c, macos, zxing

I've downloaded `zxing` sdk for OS X and tried to compile the `OS X` demo project (located in examples). But build fails with the following error:
`Lexical or Preprocessor issue`: `ZXing/ZXCapture.h file not found`

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the header paths?

See http://yannickloriot.com/2011/04/how-to-install-zxing-in-xcode-4/#sthash.a1mrhcRM.dpbs

Answer (score 0):

If you checkout the svn trunk and build the example from where it stands, it should build without issue. If you've only checked out part of the trunk or moved the projects, it probably won't because things won't be where the project files expect. If you're building your own project, you need to make sure the include paths point to the right places and that the libraries are included in the Build Phases of the target.

Generally people can help more of you paste the error (including the command that caused the error) from the build log.